# Updating Facebook business page when user is offline

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

I have `offline_access` and `manage_pages` permission but I keep getting all sorts of OAuth errors - with the code below I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token:
>   The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the
>   password.

I saved both the user access token and the page access token in a database and then try to use it to update a page the user is admin of when the user is offline. I cannot seem to make this work:

```
$access_token = User token got when user was logged in;
$news_token = Page token got when user was logged in;

// $accounts_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?" . $access_token;

            $page_info = $facebook->api("/$news_page?fields=access_token");
                     $args = array(
                                  'access_token'  => $news_token,
                                  'message'       => $u,
                                  'link'          => $news_url,
                                  'description'   => $u,
                                  'name'          => $news_title,
                                  'picture'       => $image
                                  );

                  $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
                  echo $news_source."(Offline): ".$u."<br />\n";
```

The commented out line above shows another thing I tried to no avail.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

offline_access is deprecated.

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/